# IE11 showing "active content removed" instead of map for Leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet, internet-explorer-11

For my site everything works great on a few computers, but a certain user is getting the message "Active Content Removed" instead of showing the map generated using leaflet.js

What causes this message to show up in IE11 instead of showing the map?

Is it possible the user's internet is blocking the JavaScript for my site and I need to get it added to the approved list?  If so, how can I easily check this?  I have added a `<noscript>` tag to check if JavaScript is cut off.

Comment: Sounds like an ActiveX control is being blocked. User could enable ActiveX controls, but really you shouldn't be using them. What kind of map/plugins are you using in Leaflet? I can't think of any that would use ActiveX?

Comment: Spudley let me get the code condensed and place it here.  It uses Openstreetmaps for the data.  Not sure if that plays into it.